# ADO.NET: How to bulk copy rows in a DataTable into another

Tags: vb.net, datatable, ado.net, dataset

A legacy application is copying 100K records in one `DataTable` into another like so:

```
For index = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count() - 1
    Dim column1 = CType(dataTable.Rows(index).Item("column1"), Integer)
    Dim column2 = CType(dataTable.Rows(index).Item("column2"), Integer)
    Dim column3 = CType(dataTable.Rows(index).Item("column3"), Integer)

    Dim dataRow = ds.Tables("MyTable").NewRow

    dataRow("column1") = column1
    dataRow("column2") = column2
    dataRow("column3") = column3

    ds.Tables("MyTable").Rows.Add(dataRow)
Next
```

This seems to be very slow as we need to iterate 100K times and add a new row. Are there any .NET APIs to bulk copy rows to decrease the time it takes to copy everything? The source `DataTable` has a lot more columns whereas the destination is a subset. We could refactor the code to only use the source, but this is a complex app and it will require regression testing since both source and destination tables are global variables and used in many places.

Answer (score 0):

How about it ? "dataTable.Copy()"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy?view=netframework-4.8

```
 // Create an object variable for the copy.
    DataTable copyDataTable;
    copyDataTable = table.Copy();
```

Comment: I can try this, but `Copy` copies the schema, right? The source table has dozens of columns, but we only need 3 columns in the destination.

Comment: Ok, you can try something like that.

DataTable newTable = new DataView(yourTable).ToTable("name", false, "col1", "col2", "col3");

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataView_ToTable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure by how much but I would expect this to be faster:

```
Dim newTable = oldTable.DefaultView.ToTable(False,
                                            {"column1",
                                             "column2",
                                             "column3"})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to map column names to different names? For example, I'd like to map column1 to columnA, column2 to columnB, and column3 to columnC.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the original question so is beyond the scope of this thread. That said, you could change the column names afterwards easily enough.